# Harmonic function satisfying given condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In trying to solve a homework problem I end up having the equation $\Delta f=0$ knowing that $f(x)=f(\||x\||^2)$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. In 2-d it leads me to $f_{x_1} + f_{x_2} + x_1 f_{x_1x_1} + x_2 f_{x_2x_2} = 0$. From there I am tempted to separate the variables and have a system of two pdes which are pretty easy to solve. If I cannot make this assumption I don't know how to proceed. I would appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

Comment: the form of $f$ suggests that you consider it in polar coordinates. The angular dependence drops out and you end up with an ODE.

Comment: You could also look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251318/find-all-harmonc-radial-functions/1251482#1251482.  When $n>2$ the natural replacement for $\log |x|$  is $|x|^{n-2}.$

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking for $f(x)=g(\|x\|)$, there shouldn't be a squared term, this is because the Laplace operator is rotation invariant, so you can seek a radial solution. Now applying $\Delta$ to $g$, you will end up with an ODE in the variable $r=\|x\|$, which you can solve to find the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation.

Note that $$\partial_{x_i}r=\frac{x_i}{r}$$ and $$\partial_{x_ix_i}r=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x_i^2}{r^3}$$

Comment: That makes more sense I think you might be right, there must be a typo in the initial assumption.